# Can shops use card payments to track/profile customers?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, payment, privacy, tracking

Can shops use payment information when you pay with a debit or credit card to track a customer's buying habits?

In other words can a shopkeeper link different purchases at different times in his shop together if they were done with the same card or payed from the same bank account?

By 'can' I mean both technically and legally. The legal part of course depends on jurisdiction and maybe on the terms of the payment provider, so please include that in your answer where relevant.

I know banks track the payments that are made with a card, I am wondering if shops can do so as well.

Comment: Technically is the easy part. Legally and contractually, there seem to be some restriction. My understanding, though I've never seen anything authoritative on the issue, is that stores can scrape the card name, which, along with the zip they ask for (illegal in California), can be correlated to uniquely identify  many people. I have heard, but would like authoritative confirmation, that US stores cannot scrape the card number (even if then hashed or transformed) for any use other than the transaction at hand.

Comment: I know for a fact that this is done in the UK on a regular basis, it's one reason I tend to pay with cash

Answer (score 16):

I know for a fact that this is happening as I helped implement such a solution for a merchant that has multiple brands.

For the one that I worked on actual credit card numbers were not used, but tokens that represent credit card numbers.  Without getting into too much security stuff, it is was a [one way thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).  A customer's credit card number would always result in the same token, but going the other way was pretty much impossible.  Even if the tokens were stolen, they would be useless to thieves.

Most companies implementing these solutions are only interested targeted marketing.  For example a restaurant chain might show that the owner of a given credit card ordered vegetarian options for most meals.  It would be a waste, and perhaps offensive to send such a customer a coupon for $5 off a steak dinner.

I would also say that most of these companies are interested in protecting their customer's identity and would use a token type method even if they did not risk compliance issues.

Comment: Pete, I added a link to one-way functions. I hope you don't mind. It's exactly how I would have implemented something like this. :)

Comment: Ancedotally, I've noticed that Home Depot seems to do something like this.  Whenever I buy something with my card at Home Depot it knows my e-mail address and asks if I want an e-mailed receipt.  Unless they were storing my card (or a hash/token from it) they would have no way of knowing who I was in order to show me my e-mail address.

Comment: The naiive search space is 10^15 + 10^14 (if you allow for 15-digit card numbers, primarily AmEx; the 10% difference really isn't that large, though), because the last digit is always a check digit. About a 2^50 search space, and on top of that, easy to search incrementally. Not that hard for a determined attacker unless you are doing some serious hash iterations.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Are you forgetting that any sane person using a hash on credit card numbers would also be using a salt? Thus, your calculation for search space size applies to *each* token, not *all* tokens. Moreover, companies caring about security would likely be using some algorithm like Bcrypt which would be much harder to brute-force than MD5 or SHA1, for example.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice, for anyone who isn't a security expert, salted Bcrypt and MD5 look the same -- they're both one-way functions.

Comment: To continue with the Home Depot example, if you don't have a receipt, but you do have the credit card you used to buy the item, they are able to look up the sales record.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: The purpose of salt is to make it impossible to determine whether two passwords match.  The purpose of the described tokens is to determine whether two transactions were performed with the same card.  How could one salt the tokens without making them useless?

Comment: @supercat You don't salt the tokens. The tokens, to my understanding, is the result of the hash. You would use salt + the card number. This way, you couldn't iterate every card number through the hash algorithm to get matching hashes. The hashes wouldn't be the same, due to the salt. But the salt is stored, so that when you do salt + card number on the next transaction, the same hash is generated.

Comment: @supercat: although the answer here says, "protecting their customer's identity", it also says, "targeted marketing", for which you need the customer's name and address. So I'll go out on a limb and guess that you could use the name on the credit card to look up (or generate randomly on first use) a salt, then use that salt to hash the card number to a token. It would mean there's only one salt per customer (name) instead of one salt per card, but that could be finessed a bit. I am *not* a credit card processing compliance officer and my opinion should not be taken as advice ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop " it also says, "targeted marketing", for which you need the customer's name and address." Not necessarily. My usual supermarket prints out coupons for special offers at the checkout tills. Some of them are obviously targeted at one's purchasing history over time, not just based on the current shopping basket.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice What Mark said about salted bcrypt and MD5. Besides, you only really need one credit card number at a time...

Comment: @SteveJessop: I hadn't considered the possibility of combining the account number with the encoded name in producing a hashed token, which would increase the search space enough to make reverse-engineering the tokens impractical.  Not sure how one would go about handling people who change their name, though.

Comment: @supercat: if you're hashing the name and card number together to get a token, and keying everything off that token, then you've already accepted you'll lose track and start from scratch whenever the card number changes. I wouldn't consider it a problem to do the same when the name changes. After all, this is fairly casual tracking, it's not an account the user controls and nor are we trying to prevent people evading us (which they easily can do for example by paying cash, if they really care to).

Comment: Using all the available information on a credit card and a good slow hashing function such as bcrypt or script it should be very difficult to reverse such hash tokens, but given the track record of password storage at companies I wouldn't bet many companies are doing the cryptographically right thing in this case.

Answer (score 6):

There was a story of a store, Target, that started sending a 16-17 year old girl advertisements geared toward a pregnant woman. The father got upset and talked to the local store manager. Ultimately, she *was* pregnant. But still, creepy story. They profiled her based on purchases.

(See Ben's comment below, with link to the story. I recalled the anecdote pretty well.)

Comment: Here is a [Time magazine article about it](http://techland.time.com/2012/02/17/how-target-knew-a-high-school-girl-was-pregnant-before-her-parents/); the article specifically says that Target used an ID number that they tied to the girl's credit card to track her purchases.  [Other articles covering the same story](https://www.google.com/search?q=target+sending+girl+advertisements+for+pregnancy) say similar things.